# Can anyone explain one result regarding the correlation of Brownian motions?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $B_i(t), B_j(t)$ be two Brownian motion on a filtered probability space. Let {$\theta_1, \theta_2$} be a solution to the market risk of price equations and using {$\theta_1, \theta_2$}, the risk neutral Brownian motions are written as $\tilde{B_i}(t), \tilde{B_j}(t)$. It is easily shown that $$d\tilde{B_i}(t)d \tilde{B_j}(t) = \rho_{ij}(t)$$

Now suppose $\rho_{ij}(t)$ is not random, then $$dB_i(t){B_j}(t) = B_i(t)dB_i+ B_j(t)dB_i+dB_idB_j = B_i(t)dB_i+ B_j(t)dB_i+ \rho_{ij}(t)dt$$
Thus, $E[B_iB_j]=\int_0^{t}\rho_{ij}(u)du$

Similarly, $$\tilde{E}[\tilde{B_i}\tilde{B_j}]=\int_0^{t}\rho_{ij}(u)du.$$
Thus $$\tilde{E}[\tilde{B_i}\tilde{B_j}]=E[B_iB_j].$$

However, if  $\rho_{ij}(t)$ is random, $$\tilde{E}[\tilde{B_i}\tilde{B_j}]\neq E[B_iB_j].$$ 
In this case which of the previous steps fail to hold?

Answer (score 1):

If $\rho_{i, j}(t)$ is deterministic, they are indeed equal. However, if $\rho_{i, j}(t)$ is random, then
\begin{align*}
E\left(B_i(t) B_j(t) \right) &= E\left(\int_0^t \rho_{i,j}(u)du \right)\\
&= \int_0^t E(\rho_{i, j}(u)) du,
\end{align*}
and, similarly, 
\begin{align*}
\tilde{E}\left(\tilde{B}_i(t) \tilde{B}_j(t) \right) &= \int_0^t \tilde{E}(\rho_{i, j}(u)) du.
\end{align*}
They may be different.